# How should "baseSiteUrl" look like in SPSite?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Well, I am trying to get the UserToken of the Site Collection, but every time I get the error like "The Web application at XXX could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need a new request URL mapping to the intended application". So, I would like to know How the baseSiteUrl  should look like

I have tried: 
1. http://sp15/SitePages.aspx:[portnumber]
2. http://sp15/Sitepages.aspx
3. http://sp15.aspx:[portnumber]
4. http://sp15.aspx

I am in a desperate situation. Any help is welcome.

```
protected string baseSiteUrl = "[should be base site Url]";
        protected SPUserToken SystemAccountUserToken { get; }

        public BaseAPIController()
        {
            SystemAccountUserToken = new SPSite(baseSiteUrl).SystemAccount.UserToken;
        }
```

I expected the output: [userToken], but the actual output is "The Web application at XXX could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need a new request URL mapping to the intended application"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove SitePages.aspx just use this format:

http://sp15:[portnumber]/

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp:2013/"))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPUserToken usertoken = web.CurrentUser.UserToken;
            }
```